# Unable to create Custom Attributes in Azure B2C AD

Tags: azure, azure-ad

We are using Azure B2C AD integration to our project. As part of this integration all our user's verification would be done using MS Azure interface (using different identities like Facebook, Google, etc)
To get this working we created a Tenant in Azure portal and within this Tenant we created an App with our policies and attributes.

I am able to create Tenant and App with all my policies and attributes for UAT in the Azure portal. But when i created one more tenant (new one) on the portal again, and when i tried updating the attributes - i am able to update the policies but getting error when i create a custom attribute.

I have already verified all related permissions and I am Admin user to the azure portal.

Any idea of what could be missing on the Production Azure B2C AD which is restricting creation of Custom Attributes.

Attached below is a screen of the error, i am receiving on the portal - 
[image: Azure portal error message]

Comment: If you expand your question with how this is relevant to you in a Sitecore context, your question would come under the https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/29/the-pee-wee-herman-rule/. Otherwise you risk, the community voting to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raised a ticket with Microsoft to look into the issue. They have got their back-end team to look into the issue, and the investigation result seems that something in Azure platform didn't worked as expected, that caused the issue to happen.
Their back end team has now made the relevant changes to get the functionality working now.